# Change the connection string of nopCommerce?

Tags: connection-string, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce and I need to remove the connection string in the settings.txt file and insert the web.config file. How can i do this?

Comment: What have *you* tried? Be more clear on "remove" the connection string - does that mean you want to programmatically *edit* that text file?

Comment: if what I want to do is change the way how I communicate with the database, as in nopCommerce the connection string is in the settings.txt file and not in the web.config

Answer (score 5):

The most straightforward way to move the connection string out of settings.txt and into the web.config is to modify the `Nop.Core.Data.DataSettingsManager`. Specifically the `LoadSettings()` and `SaveSettings()` methods. You can store the connection string wherever you'd like (ideally in web.config), as long as those two methods read and write the configuration.

A rough example of the `DataSettingsManager` updated to support storing the connection string in web.config can be found in this Gist: http://git.io/vUPcI Just copy the connection string from settings.txt to web.config and name the connection "DefaultConnection" or adapt the code accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Just do two steps

1. Replace two method `LoadSettings` and `SaveSettings` in `\nopCommerce\Libraries\Nop.Core\Data\DataSettingsManager.cs`. Code from link of @Stephen Kiningham

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Load settings
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="filePath">File path; pass null to use default settings file path</param>
   /// <returns></returns>
   public virtual DataSettings LoadSettings(string filePath = null)
   {            
       try
       {
           System.Configuration.Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);
           return new DataSettings
           {
               DataConnectionString = webConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString,
               DataProvider = webConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ProviderName
           };
       }
       catch (NullReferenceException)
       {
           return new DataSettings();
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Save settings to a file
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="settings"></param>
   public virtual void SaveSettings(DataSettings settings)
   {            
       if (null == settings) throw new ArgumentNullException("settings");

       System.Configuration.Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);

       webConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString = settings.DataConnectionString;
       webConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ProviderName = settings.DataProvider;

       webConfig.Save();
   }
   ```
2. Add connection string to your web config web.config

   ```xml
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="DefaultConnection"
            connectionString=" Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=nopcommerce;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False"
            providerName="sqlserver">
       </add>
   </connectionStrings>
   ```

Answer (score 2):

[1] In .NET Core (3.1 | NopCommerce 4.3) I created various appsettings.json files (including appsettings.json, appsettings.Development.json, appsettings.Integration.json, appsettings.Staging.json) and logic (beyond this discuss) determines the the correct settings to be used in the proper environment etc.

[2] \nopCommerce\Libraries\Nop.Core\Data\DataSettingsManager.cs
I created the following method:

```
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var env = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        string appSettingsFileName = env switch
        {
            "Development" => "appsettings.Development.json",
            "Production" => "appsettings.json",
            "Staging" => "appsettings.Staging.json",
            "Integration" => "appsettings.Integration.json",
            _ => "appsettings.json",
        };

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile(appSettingsFileName).Build();
        string connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

        return connectionString;
    }
```

(returns the proper connection string for the proper environment)

[3] In `LoadSettings` -- I didn't change *anything* to get down to the line

`Singleton<DataSettings>.Instance = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSettings>(text);`

... I just **added a new line below** to replace the `.ConnectionString` with the connectionstring determined from our new method:

`Singleton<DataSettings>.Instance.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();`

**important:**
When I ran it there were three or four places where there was a switch (case > default:) that was looking for a provider etc -- But I just copied the settings from MsSql down to the default: and it worked fine.  I know this is sloppy but I am never using MySql for this project and so far as I am concerned its a non-issue.  Either way - I broke it to make it work (multiple Azure App environments are more important).

I suggest they should have built it the regular way and just provided us with a SQL script for deployment (over engineered a non-issue?) since we usually have to do that anyway for custom development (seems silly to me to hard code a data settings file in App_Data) - but I trust their logic.

Comment: This is the way most professional developers work. I'd love the idea of switching databases to test if it works in our stage wise environments. The Core had to be touched. But I guess that's something we can live with.

Answer (score 1):

Please add this to your web.config under Nop.Web project :

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyConnectionString" 
connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=False;UserID=userName;Password=password" 
</connectionStrings>
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the connection to the web.config, you have to specify the providerName="sqlserver".

> Ex) ;Initial Catalog=;Integrated
>   Security=False;User ID=;Password=;Connect
>   Timeout=30;Encrypt=True" 
>            providerName="sqlserver" />

This is because the EfDataProviderManager in Nop.Data has a check for the provider name, and will throw an exception if you put the normal

> providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: This was very important. I didn't notice the nuance in the connection string in the other answer above and used the typical providerName.